# Telegram enable notification on muted group/channel

Tags: telegram

I need to enable notifications from a muted channel on my telegram web-client.

As now I've enabled the notifications from inside the Android app on that specific channel and I've registered an handle for the UpdateNotifySettings. Once received I send a request: account.updateNotifySettings. However I'm not receiving notifications about new messages, am I supposed to do other requests in order to correctly activate them?

Edit: Consider that from my RPC to account.updateNotifySettings I receive a TLBoolTrue.